# UDP Range Nat Translation port forwarding RPT Traffic to inside host PBX Cisco ASA 5505 8.2a

Tags: networking, firewall, cisco-asa, voip, asterisk

I have an Asterisk based PBX that I'm providing VoIP services with, My gateway is a Cisco ASA 5505 running 8.2 and I only have one public IP Available along with other services I provide with that IP. I also do not have a smartnet account available to do a IOS update.

I do have calls working currently by  simply forwarding all traffic to that host for about a minute and then removing the static NAT route, After I remove the route Voice traffic still gets forwarded to the inside host like it should, how ever if i ever add a remote phone that needs to connect externally it will not work.

What I need to do is forward the UDP port range of 10000-20000, however it seems I can't create a port map for UDP, or define a range of ports for UDP in a static Route.

SIP (5060) is properly forwarded but that only handles the session not voice, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The ASA doesn't seem to be capable of this. I'd love to find out I'm wrong, though...

Comment: 8.4 seems to be capable of it, I managed to upgrade the IOS but every time Nat the ports it states the ports can not be reserved.